# Clearing cache for performance testing in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb, mongodb-query

I know when testing performance of queries in relational databases you typically clear the cache before you run the query to get a real idea of what performance will be like the first time the data is queried.  Is there something similar in MongoDB?

I found some [query plan cache clearing stuff](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/js-plan-cache/), but nothing that would clear cached data.  Is there such a thing in MongoDB?  If so, can someone point me toward some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution assumes you are on a Unix-like system.

I haven't done a lot of DBA of MongoDB, but I believe that [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivBcMSYA3zs) contains the answer for clearing cached data.

The relevant portion of the video coming at about [4:57 in the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivBcMSYA3zs#t=297) and the command is:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

As the video explains, using `1` should be sufficient for most cases, but if you want to make absolutely sure, you can use `3`. And if you (like the instructor from the [MongoDB class](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M202/about)) find that command to be "inelegant", you can use:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=1
```

There are other videos in that lecture series which [introduce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nY0pSydF_rg) and [demonstrate](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rlBgWbwG9E) "pre-[heating data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmG5OoI4ozg)" to get the working set into memory before having your application access the machine so that users don't experience the poor performance of reading from disk.